# Replacing the blank cells with specific value

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to change the blank cells into specific value of 16. However, the value it shows is like 44877. I tried changing the format, but it won't change.

The link is here: [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17cm-C9ueGSqkK4kvAQCcSY_YYjPJ7EZ3T6Njfc9NjkM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Use `isblank()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    isblank(A2:A), 16, 
    today() - A2:A > 1, today() - A2:A, 
    today() - A2:A < -1, 0, 
    true, iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

In the event the cells you call "blank" are actually not blank but contain a formula that yields zero-length text strings `""`, you need to consider that zero-length text strings are different from truly blank values.

To detect both zero-length text strings and truly blank values, replace `isblank(A2:A)` with `not(len(A2:A))`.

`44877` is the dateserial value for today, 12 November 2022. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: Hi @doubleunary, thank you for this. However, when I tried your formula on the sample sheet, blank cells remained to be blank wherein it should be a specific number which is "16". Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hi @doubleunary, I tried changing the value after the isblank, from error(1/0), to "16". It worked, but I don't know if its right 

Comment: It sounds like the cells you call "blank" are actually not blank but contain a formula that yields zero-length text strings `""`. Zero-length text strings are different from truly blank values. Replace `isblank(A2:A)` with `not(len(A2:A))` to detect both zero-length text strings and truly blank values.

Answer (score 0):

@doubleunary option works, obviously! As she/he suggested, the option where A is blank should be first. You're missing some scenarios: first you have >1 and <-1, if you want those values to be considered you should add an equal: >=1 <=-1

And also the one in which it is the same date as Today () -- so you should set first if A2:A is empty, then if it is equal, and then if its greater or smaller:

```
=ArrayFormula((IFS(isblank(A2:A), "16",TODAY()=A2:A, "Is today",TODAY()-A2:A>=1, TODAY()-A2:A, TODAY()-A2:A<=-1, "0")))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, t, 
 IF(a="",  16, 
 IF(t-a >  1, t-a-1,
 IF(t-a =  0, t-a, 
 IF(t-a < -1, 0, )))))(A2:A, TODAY()))
```

[image]